# Is there any way i can check if mosquitto is indeed using my custom mosquitto.conf file instead of the default one?

Tags: docker, mosquitto

The question is self explanatory

I am running mosquitto in a container and i am persisting `/mosquitto` using `EFS` so `mosquitto.conf` is persisting

I want to test if mosquitto is indeed using my custom `mosquitto.conf` instead of the default one

How do i do this ?

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
listener 1883
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

**UPDATE**

```
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
log_type all
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format [%H:%M:%S]
```

Adding this to `mosquitto.conf` worked as suggested by hardillb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mosquitto prints out the config file it is using on the second line of its log output when started.

Without changing something fundamental e.g. the port it listens on, and testing it you have assume that it is using the file at location.

Comment: where do i check for logs ? do i check `mosquitto/log` ? because that is empty everytime i run it  i am gonna attach my modified `mosquitto.conf` do i have to add anything to store logs please check

Comment: Normally containers log to stdout

Comment: Well, you seem to have removed the logging commands from the `mosquitto.conf` that ships in the container....

Comment: Please read the `mosquitto.conf` man page https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html

Comment: i added the logs commands and got logs successfully working thanks :)